# Zero Message Length HASH

Tags: hash

What does it mean by a HASH of a message with zero length or rather why is it required? 
What could be a possible scenario where this is used?

Also note that, for a given HASHing algorithm, the hash value of a zero length message is essentially pre-defined.

Comment: No, my question intends to ask something different. I have edited it to make it clearer now.

Comment: read the answer in the linked question carefully, it is defined as a nonempty string, so that some properties in Maarten bodewes' answer are satisfied.

Comment: It still doesn't answer "What could be a possible scenario where this is used?"

Comment: If you are using a hash module for example, then you can hash an empty string and make sure that the output matches what is says online, to make sure that the hash module is working as it should be

Comment: @kodlu I myself see it as a related but not identical question, and asking for use cases is something different and allows for a more detailed answer.

Comment: @SamG101 True, but that would work for any other string as well, and it would not e.g. show issues where multiple blocks of data are hashed and the padding or length encoding is mucked up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hash of a zero-length message is defined for several reasons:

- There's no reason not to define it. If (as you assume) it'll never be used, then it doesn't matter whether it's defined and there's no reason to avoid defining it.
- Having it undefined would create a weird exceptional case that'd need to be handled by anything that uses the hash, just in case it ever happens. Weird exceptions tend to lead to bugs, bugs tend to cause vulnerabilities, and cryptographers hate vulnerabilities and the design choices that cause them.
- In practice, it *will* be used. One common use of hashes is to create a fingerprint of the contents of files, and empty (zero-length) files are entirely normal.

As for your point that for a given HASHing algorithm, the hash value of a zero length message is essentially pre-defined: that's true, but it's also true of any other specific message. The hash of "a" is essentially pre-defined, as is the hash of "foo", "This is a message", etc.